# Selenium-webdriver java dropdown issue "Element should have been "select" but was "div""

Tags: selenium-webdriver, element

When try to click on the Signout in the Amazon site the error message "Element should have been "select" but was "div" is displayed. It looks like either of the CSS selector and XPATh identifier is not working at the end of the code. PLease help to resolve this issue.

```
import java.sql.Driver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class FirstClass {

    private static final String SeleniumWait = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Documents\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.id("nav-link-accountList")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("ap_email")).sendKeys("welcom@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("ap_password")).sendKeys("Password");
        driver.findElement(By.id("signInSubmit")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='nav-link-accountList']/span[1]")).click();
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='nav-al-container']")).click();
        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        jse.executeScript("scroll(0, 50);"); 

        Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='nav-al-container']")));
        dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Not test? Sign Out");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);// 1 minute 
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("//*[@id='nav-item-signout']/span")));
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#nav-item-signout > span")).click();//CSS selector

        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='nav-item-signout']/span")).click(); //XPATH
```

Answer (score 0):

in following line :

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='nav-al-container']")));
```

It only works with dropdowns ahving `<select>` html tag, but in your HTML it belongs to `<div>` tag.
You need to handle this dropdown with different approach.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to hover on `By.xpath("//*[@id='nav-link-accountList']")` instead of clicking on it by using `Actions` class.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='nav-link-accountList']"));
action.build().perform();
```

2. Then you need to click on the element located by `By.id("nav-item-signout")` to sign out.